# Is it okay to fallback on Random if SecureRandom can't be used?

Tags: java, random, exception

I have a Java library which has a class (ShrubSecureRandom) which uses SecureRandom to generate numbers, sentences, and the like.
The method it uses to get the Random class goes like this:

```
public Random getSRGInstance() {
    Random instanceToReturn;
    try {
        instanceToReturn = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("SecureRandom algorithm not found! Reverting to INSECURE Random instance...");
        instanceToReturn = new Random();
    }
    return instanceToReturn;
}
```

If the code gets an exception while creating the SecureRandom class (NoSuchAlgorithmException, etc.), it will use a Random class instead.
My question is: **is this safe? If not, what should I do instead?**

Comment: `java.util.Random` is not secure.

Comment: @ifiy6 I know that, but the method only uses Random if SecureRandom can't be accessed.

Comment: @VinceEmigh It hasn't been solved already. This try/catch block is for the possible error of there being no SHA1PRNG algorithm.

Comment: @SahibPrime Of course it isn't safe to fall back to an insecure random number generator. The correct course of action is to fail fatally.

Comment: I agree with @Kayaman, just include a check (SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")) at startup to fail early

Comment: @Kayaman Even if the library user doesn't want it to fail fatally?

Comment: This kinda comes across as a silent failure.  I'll re-ask your question another way:  Would you ever want your code to appear to succeed but be woefully insecure?

Comment: @Taylor Now that you put it that way, the answer's obvious. Thanks! I was just unsure if I wanted my library to fail catastrophically.

Comment: Then, why use a securerandom at all, if you can live without it ?

Comment: IMO, yes.  The alternative is to fail in a much more catastrophic (i.e. insecure) fashion. ;)

Comment: @Alex Now I see the flaw in my logic.

Comment: @Taylor either being insecure or being insecure.... i wonder which one to pick?

Comment: So, in failing, should I use a System.exit call, or something different?

Comment: Failing deterministically (i.e. throw exception if can't find secure algo): not insecure.  Falling back to insecure impl: silently insecure.  IMO, throw an exception.

Comment: You said you have this in a library code. What is the library author's justification (if any) for implementing such silent fallback to an insecure mechanism?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade I'm the author, and I don't actually have a justification ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not constrained on the RNG algorithm (e.g. you are simulating a dice in a game, and you want to use something better than Random), you can return a `new SecureRandom()` which implements the default random number algorithm for your Java VM. In that case you don't care about the implementation details, but you are guaranteed that the generator is **cryptographically strong**.

Note that certain uses do require an specific algorithm. For instance, when generating AES-256 encryption keys, the RNG must provide at least 256 bits of entropy, which SHA1PRNG doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments in the answer, it seems to be unsafe. The best way is to **fail catastrophically**, by throwing `NoSuchAlgorithmException`.

Comment: Don't use `System.exit`: that always causes the JVM to exit. Throw the exception - the `NoSuchAlgorithmException` - and allow the caller of the method to decide how to deal with the problem. The caller may have a strategy to recover from this problem (which I hope is not using `Random` instead).

Comment: Maybe wrap NSAE in an IllegalStateException or some such (you may have your own applicable exception to wrap this in too)